# Can't Get GET Query Parameters when 'urlFormat' is Set to 'path'

Tags: yii, seo

I have tried `echo $_GET['id']`, `var_dump($_GET)`, but both don't give the desired results.

After enabling `urlFormat` in the application's main.php file, I can no longer get the query parameter called 'id'.

The url's are of the format: index.php/controller/action/param (I don't have an htaccess file)

Right now the URL looks like: `index.php/article/read/daily_proxy_list`

Using `var_dump($_GET)` returns only:

```
array
  'daily_proxy_list' => string '' (length=0)
```

And here's how I create the URL to point to this location:

```
$this->createUrl('article/read', array('id'=>$key));
```

My question is, how do I get the query parameter named 'id' (or any other name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From yii documentation

```
Since version 1.1.4, Yii has added support for automatic action parameter binding. That is, a controller action method can define named parameters whose value will be automatically populated from $_GET by Yii.
```

So in order to get the value `$_GET['id']` , you simply add an argument `$id` to the `actionRead()`. Yii will automatically populate it with `$_GET['id']`

```
public function actionRead($id)
{
    var_dump($id);
}
```

For more info and examples refer to [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#action)

Comment: This did not solve the issue. It seems that it only appears when I use the default 'id' query parameter. If I use any other name such as `index.php/article/read?name=daily_proxy_list` it works fine. Other scenarios that work fine as well: `index.php/article/read/id/daily_proxy_list` ('id' specifically included), `index.php/article/read?id=daily_proxy_list`(not using Mod_Rewrite for the query parameters, which kind of escapes the point)

Comment: do you have any url rules specified n the application config? Then post it as an edit to the question

Comment: No, besides `'urlFormat'=>'path', 'showScriptName'=>false,`, I haven't made any changes to the standard main.php configuration file.

Comment: @ColorWP.com your config cntains `'showScriptName'=>false` and you get urls like `index.php/article/read?name=daily_proxy_list`. That is impossible. And remember if you want to use `'showScriptName'=>false` you **must** use some .`htaccess` rewrite rules

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [parseUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseUrlRule#parseUrl-detail) with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] or similar?

Comment: No, but I was guessing there is a more practical way of doing this (e.g. a built in YII function) instead of trying to split the URL into separate parts.